# Enable/Disable TaskManager

Tags: c#, .net, regedit

```
        public static void ToggleTaskManager(string keyValue)
        {
            RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");
            objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", keyValue);
            objRegistryKey.Close();
        }


        private void btnDisableTaskManager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConsoleDisplay.ToggleTaskManager("1");
        }

        private void btnEnableTaskManager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConsoleDisplay.ToggleTaskManager("0");
        }
```

For Disable/Enable TaskManager used above function but when i disable first time then it disable correctly.But when i click on enable button TaskManager not enabled.

Comment: Maybe you need to restart the computer for the changes to take effect?
Does the registry key get changed?

Comment: yes the regisry key changed when click on disable "0" and click on enable "1"...And i have restart pc but changes doesnt effect..

Comment: Um, applications should not modify system policies. Only the network administrator should do that, and the way to do it is via the group policy object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, delete will work. Means, use this code to toggle:

```
    public void ToggleTaskManager()
    {
        RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
            @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
        if (objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") == null)
            objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1");
        else
            objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
        objRegistryKey.Close();
    }
```

or this code to set:

```
    public void SetTaskManager(bool enable)
    {
        RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
            @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
        if (enable && objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") != null)
            objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
        else
            objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1");
        objRegistryKey.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Deleting the Key instead of setting the value to False

Comment: Check out this Article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public void SetTaskManager(bool enable)
    {
        RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
            @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
        if (enable && objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") != null)
            objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
        else
            objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1");
        objRegistryKey.Close();
    }
```

For Enable/Desable: (Sorry, my English is very bad...)

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.F1:
                {
                    SetTaskManager(Convert.ToBoolean(1));
                }
                break;
        }
```

Note: You must have administrator access to run the program.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

answer 4 is Okey But Uu need one more litte code this %100 true (**RegistryValueKind.DWord**) ;

```
RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
        @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
        if (objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") == null)
            objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        else
            objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
        objRegistryKey.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

for disabling TaskManager you must set a DWord string in Registry( User Local Machine instead of Current User).
Use following code.( It not working in windows 7)

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System",true);
key.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.Close();
```

for That user application must run under Admin Permission. change following change in app.manifest for using application in Admin Permission

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```