# edit user profile at registry when user logged off

Tags: c#, registry

I need to edit windows user(domain or local) profile in registry,like disabling Task manager for specified user.

I do this in HKey_Users[User SID]...

But this address exists only if user logged in and As soon as the user loge off,[SID] tree removed

How can i do this if user is not logged in?

Comment: It doesnt disapear on the machines Im on... You could probably look at group policies

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16610567/1997232) works?

Comment: i want to do this for another user,not current user

Comment: Are those local or domain users?

Comment: users may be any of local and domain later

Answer (score 0):

You can use vbscript to cycle thru each users hive. Configure your own profile the way you need it. Export the reg key. Replace all instances of 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the reg file with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\TempHive save the .reg file. Now run the vbscript. Been doing it this way for many years. Note this applies changes to all current and future users except for the current logged on user (reg.exe cannot load a hive currently in use). If you need it to exclude some users, I will need to tweak the script.

```
On Error Resume Next

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strWinDir = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
strSystemDrive = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strSystemDrive & "\Users")

Set colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders
  For Each objSubfolder in colSubfolders
    WshShell.Run(strWinDir & "\System32\cmd.exe /c " & strWinDir & "\System32\reg.exe load HKLM\TempHive " & chr(34) & "C:\Users\" & objSubfolder.Name & "\NTUser.dat" & chr(34)),0, True
    WshShell.Run(strWinDir & "\regedit.exe /i /s " & strSystemDrive & "\PostInstall\PropPref.reg"),0, True
    WshShell.Run(strWinDir & "\System32\cmd.exe /c " & strWinDir & "\System32\reg.exe unload HKLM\TempHive"),0, True
  Next

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: excuse me,but i do not understand the steps,can you write step by step your answer,thank you and very excuse me